# WPF Custom Event Handler

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker, eventhandler

I have implemented the code for DatePicker `https://github.com/cmyksvoll/HighlightDatePicker` but I cannot use SelectedDateChanged in WPF with the error `ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type`

I have tried to create custom Even Handler for "SelectedDateChanged"  but the HighlightDatePicker class is static and I cannot register it so that my method will be called in MainWindow

WPF:

```
<hdp:HighlightDatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate}"  HighlightedDates="{Binding HighlightedDates}" HighlightBrush="LawnGreen" SelectedDateChanged="ProviderDateChanged"/>
```

My MainWindow method to call:

```
        public void ProviderDateChanged(object Sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        { // fetch data to display }
```

HighlightedDatePicker Class:

```
    public class HighlightDatePicker : DatePicker
{
     static HighlightDatePicker()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(HighlightDatePicker), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(HighlightDatePicker)));


    public static readonly DependencyProperty HighlightedDatesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("HighlightedDates", typeof(IList<HighlightedDate>), typeof(HighlightDatePicker));



    public IList<HighlightedDate> HighlightedDates
    {
        get { return (IList<HighlightedDate>)GetValue(HighlightedDatesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HighlightedDatesProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HighlightBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("HighlightBrush", typeof(Brush),
        typeof(HighlightDatePicker), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Orange));

    public Brush HighlightBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(HighlightBrushProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HighlightBrushProperty, value); }
    }
}
public class HighlightedDate
{
    public HighlightedDate(DateTime date, string description)
    {
        Date = date;
        Description = description;
    }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In Visual Studio write SelectedDateChanged="" and press Tab. VS will automatically add a method with the right signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct signature for the handler method for the SelectedDateChanged event is:

```
    private void ProviderDateChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // fetch data to display
    }
```